# Why do plugins have to check if they are already loaded?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system

I noticed that most of the plugins I use have a line at the start that checks if the plugin has already been loaded. It often looks similar to this:

```
if exists("g:loaded_commentary")
    finish
endif
let g:loaded_commentary = 1
```

Why do plugins have to do this? What bad things can happen if I create a plugin and don't add that "exists" guard at the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly a pre-plugin manager era thing that permits to prevent a plugin file from being loaded. For people that still install those files directly into `~/.vim/plugin`, it still makes sense.

It could still make sense if you distribute a plugin (in the *new* sense:) made of several files that defines different things. But honestly, it'd be simpler in that case to have options that permits to fine tune what shall always be defined and/or how.

Note: it can also be used to check whether a plugin has been loaded (there exist other methods though), or to obtain the plugin version if we use that variable to store a version id instead of a boolean.

EDIT: Vim help describes another use case that makes a lot of sense (`:h write-plugin`)

> Or the system administrator has dropped it in the system-wide plugin directory, but a user has his own plugin he wants to use.  Then the user must have a chance to disable loading this specific plugin.

Comment: Thanks. That link to the documentation was exactly what I was looking for as well.